# SpamAssassin Presets

Tags: email-server, spamassassin

We're currently migrating our mail from a manually administered RHEL box to a CPanel box, which I'm so excited about I will probably weep a little when it finally happens.

As part of the migration, I would love for clients to see an immediate spam reduction as spam has been a bit of a bug bear on our current server.  We already run rbls, which will continue on our new server, but as it's a fresh install without any pre-learned rules, I'm hoping there's resources out there to 'prime' spamassassin somehow with a list of common blocked IP's and blocked phrases for example, so it's ready to start blocking immediately.

Anyone know of any resources like this? Or does a fresh SpamAssassin install already have ample initial rules in place?

Comment: You are excited about moving to a cPanel-managed box? There must be something wrong with you...cPanel is a world of hurt and nothing more. If you do use cPanel, don't expect to get much help here, as cPanel and most other GUI control panels are viewed as abominations and wholly counter to good sysadmin practices.

Comment: Interestingly, one of the reasons we're moving is because we've used multiple server admin companies, and whenever we've had any issues they can't resolve (which is a lot), they've said "you would be much better off with a cpanel server". We don't have the resources for a full time sysadmin, which is pretty much what you need if you don't use a control panel.

Answer (score 1):

Did you have SpamAssassin installed on your old server? If so you can issue the commands

On old server: `sa-learn --backup > rules.sa`

After you copy to new server

On new server: `sa-learn --restore ./rules.sa`

---

If you are looking for a spam database to add to your server one suggestion is to install Razor. You did not specify what operating system you are using but here are the general instructions: From http://razor.sourceforge.net/docs/doc.php?type=text&name=INSTALL

Install Perl modules from CPAN
`Time::HiRes`
    `Digest::SHA1`
            `MIME::Base64`
            `Test::Simple`
            `Test::Harness`
            `Getopt::Long`
            `File::Copy`
            `URI::Escape`

Download the latest version of Razor 
`http://sourceforge.net/projects/razor/`
Untar an cd into directory
Untar the razor-agents tarball and run:

```
perl Makefile.PL
make
make test
sudo make install
```

To create default config `sudo razor-admin -create`

> Razor v2 requires reporters to be registered so their reputations can
>      be computed over time and they can participate in the revocation
>      mechanism. Registration is done with razor-admin -register. It has to be
>      manually invoked in either of the following ways:

```
To register user foo with `s1kret' as password:

        razor-admin -register -user=foo -pass=s1kr3t

To register with an email address and have the password assigned:

        razor-admin -register -user=foo@bar.com

To have both (random) username and password assigned:

        razor-admin -register
```

Comment: We do have SpamAssassin running, but not very effectively.  It's only available globally, not on a per user basis, and isn't set to self learn.

Comment: So you are looking for a spam database? I will edit my answer.